# Data in column instead of rows

Tags: excel, database

I am getting data from SQL Server into an Excel sheet. Its a customer table containing 20 records. The columns are Customer Code, Customer Name and Customer Short Name.

What I need is instead of data coming in rows (from row 2 to row 21)... it should come in columns..  i.e. 1st three rows of column A contains respective headers (code, name and short name) and column B first row contains value of code, second row value of name and third row value of short name... same continue to column C, D, E..... till all 20 records..

Is it possible in excel?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, you can easily transpose the array with your data. Consider the following sample data in the range `A1:C4`:

[image: data]

You could now select the entire range and copy it via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> -> `Paste` -> `Transpose (T)`. A second possibility would be to enter the following formula in, e.g., cell `E1`: `=TRANSPOSE(A1:C4)`. This is a dynamic array formula in the current version (Microsoft 365). If you have an older version, you have to enter the formula as a legacy array formula by confirming the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The result is as follows:

[image: result]

---

**Edit:** Dynamic setting of range

Theoretically, assuming that the data structure remains the same in terms of the number of columns and rows, the formulaic approach will update the transposed array accordingly as the original data is updated. In the specification above, the range `A1:C4` is hard coded. While it is very likely that the number of columns will remain the same (could also be dynamically adjusted), in practice additional rows could be added/deleted from the data. In this case, you can specify the number of rows dynamically, which solves this problem:

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(A:C,1,1):INDEX(A:C,COUNTA(A:A),3))
```

Comment: Will it remain like this when I refresh the query from Excel?

Comment: @KomailNoori Technically, the formulaic approach updates the data when you update the information. However, it assumes that the size of the columns and rows remain the same. I have additionally added the approach of dynamically setting the range in case you may have extra rows.